# can't connect elasticsearch to logstash

Tags: logstash, kibana

I'm trying to connect elasticsearch to logstash on a centralized logstash aggregator

I'm running the logstash web interface over port 80 with kibana.

This is the command I'm using to start logstash :

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /etc/alternatives/logstashhome/logstash.jar agent -f      /etc/logstash/logstash.conf web --port 80
```

This is the conf I am using:

```
 [root@logstash:~] #cat /etc/logstash/logstash.conf 
  input { redis { host => "my-ip-here" 
  type => "redis-input" 
  data_type => "list"
  key =>       "logstash" } 
  }

 output {
 stdout { }
 elasticsearch{
    type => "all"
    embedded => false
    host => "my-ip-here"
    port => "9300"
    cluster => "jf"
    node_name => "logstash"
    }
 }
```

And it looks as if I am receiving data from the logstash agent (installed on another host). I see log entries streaming by after I start logstash via init script.

```
2013-10-31T02:51:53.916+0000 beta Oct 30 22:51:53 49eb8f3e-a2c1-4c12-a41f-42dbe635a9f0 sshd[23324]: Connection closed by xx.xx.xx.xx
2013-10-31T02:52:13.002+0000 beta Oct 30 22:52:12 49eb8f3e-a2c1-4c12-a41f-42dbe635a9f0 proftpd[23403]: xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx[xx.xx.xx.xx]) - FTP session opened.
2013-10-31T02:52:13.002+0000 beta Oct 30 22:52:12 49eb8f3e-a2c1-4c12-a41f-42dbe635a9f0 proftpd[23403]: xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx[xx.xx.xx.xx]) - FTP session closed.
2013-10-31T02:52:30.080+0000 beta Oct 30 22:52:29 49eb8f3e-a2c1-4c12-a41f-42dbe635a9f0 xinetd[1757]: START: nrpe pid=23405 from=xx.xx.xx.xx
2013-10-31T02:52:30.081+0000 beta Oct 30 22:52:29 49eb8f3e-a2c1-4c12-a41f-42dbe635a9f0 xinetd[1757]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=23405 duration=0(sec)
```

I can see my nagios server connecting to the beta host ( beta is the external host with the logstash agent installed and running) and some FTP sessions (not that I'm in love FTP, but hey what can ya do?)

Yet when I point my browser to the logstash server I see this message:

```
Error No index found at http://logstash.mydomain.com:9200/_all/_mapping. Please create at least one index.If you're using a proxy ensure it is configured correctly.1 alert(s)
```

This is my cluster setting in elasticsearch.yaml

```
 grep -i cluster /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml  | grep jf
 cluster.name: jf
```

My host in elasticsearch.yaml
    grep -i host  /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

```
 network.bind_host: xxx.xx.xx.xxx  # <- my logstash ip
```

I did try to add an index using the following curl:

```
[root@logstash:~] #curl -PUT http://logstash.mydomain.com:9200/_template/logstash_per_index
```

But when I reload the page I get the same error message. A bit stuck at this point. I'd appreciate any advice anyone may have!

Thanks!

Comment: Which port is ElasticSearch using? The default is 9200, but I notice your Logstash output is configured to use 9300.

Comment: @rutter  9200 is the default http port,  but port in the above contect is the tcp port.  Which the default is 9300.  ElasticSearch uses two ports.

Answer (score 1):

try to execute this

```
curl -XPUT http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/item/1 -d '{"name":"addhe warman", "description": "White hat hacker."}'
```

what was it because your elasticsearch is empty try to fill it with sample data and then find out the real problem is. good luck

Comment: for connecting you should use port `9300`

Answer (score 0):

You can check this chrome plugin once.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense/doinijnbnggojdlcjifpdckfokbbfpbo?hl=en

It's a JSON aware developer tool to ElasticSearch.Also after creating index,clear the browser cache,close the browser and retest.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of logstash? (meaning like log-file)

The version of the logstash-embedded elasticsearch must match your standalone-version.
e.g. logstash 1.3 uses elasticsearch 0.90.
logstash 1.4 uses elasticsearch 1.0

So either you have to take care to use the right elasticsearch-version or use **elasticsearch_http** as output (with port 9200) to use the REST-API.

Answer (score 0):

you should let default configuration by removing this line

```
port => "9300"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having similar issue, elasticsearch was running is different port and kibana was accessing it in 9200 port, which is mentioned in ./vendor/kibana/config.js file inside logstash home folder.